# Sanitizing a simple contact form

Tags: javascript, input, sanitization

I'm creating a simple contact form for a portfolio site in vanilla JS. I obviously don't want XSS attacks on my site or sent to my email. Nothing is going to a database or being saved, other than the info being sent to my email. Is this too simple? Am I oversimplifying something?

```
const handleScriptAttack = (input) => {
  const scriptRegex = /<script/i;
  return input.match(scriptRegex);
};
```

And then in a submit function, just run

```
  if (handleScriptAttack(contactSubject.value)) {
    return alert("Shame on you");
  }
  if (handleScriptAttack(contactMessage.value)) {
    return alert("Really?");
  }
```

And not allow the user to submit if one matches?

Comment: _"Is this too simple?"_ - I think the answer is YES, because as long as this code runs on the client browser, a user with enough knowledge can override this protection

Comment: Should be sanitized on the server. or durning rendering process...